# Fluent NHibernate Mapping IDictionary<Enum,Class> - Key saves as null

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following classes and mappings:

```
public enum VariationType
{
    Base = 1,
    RiderMain = 2,
    RiderSpouse = 3,
    RiderChild = 4,
    Family = 5,
    FamilyBase = 6
}

public class PlanParameter
{
    private IDictionary<VariationType, PlanParameterDefaultValue> _defaultValues;

    public PlanParameter()
    {
        ParameterContext = new Parameter();
    }

    public virtual Parameter ParameterContext { get; set; }

    public virtual object DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public virtual string DefaultValueString
    {
        get
        {
            return DefaultValue == null ? null : DefaultValue.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            DefaultValue = value == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, ParameterContext.Type);
        }
    }

    public virtual IDictionary<VariationType, PlanParameterDefaultValue> DefaultValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (_defaultValues == null)
                _defaultValues = new Dictionary<VariationType,  PlanParameterDefaultValue>();

            return _defaultValues;
        }
    }
}

class PlanParameterMap : ClassMap<PlanParameter>
{
    public PlanParameterMap()
    {
        Id().GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");

        References(x => x.ParameterContext,"ParameterID");

        Map(x => x.DefaultValueString);

        HasMany(x=> x.DefaultValues)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .KeyColumn("PlanParameterID").Inverse()
            .AsMap("Variation")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}


public class PlanParameterDefaultValue
{
    public virtual PlanParameter PlanParameter { get; set; }

    public virtual object DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public virtual string DefaultValueString
    {
        get
        {
            return DefaultValue == null ? null : DefaultValue.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            DefaultValue = value == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, PlanParameter.ParameterContext.Type);
        }
    }
}


class PlanParameterDefaultValueMap : ClassMap<PlanParameterDefaultValue>
{
    public PlanParameterDefaultValueMap()
    {
        Id().GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");

        Map(x => x.DefaultValueString);

        References(x => x.PlanParameter).Column("PlanParameterID");
    }
}
```

My problem is very specific to the mapping of the

```
IDictionary<VariationType, PlanParameterDefaultValue> DefaultValues
```

The enum for some reason will not save, all that's saved in it's column is null
my only solution so far was to add a VariationType Property to the Entity and map it with a lambda formula, but i really don't need the VariationType in the Entity

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The Inverse() tells NHibernate that the "mapped-to"-entity will take care of saving the key, and that the collection owner should not persist the Key. Try removing that flag.

Comment: But i need the child to know the parent - to know the PlanParameter
and that cannot be done without the Inverse as far as i can tell,
And the child doesn't know the key and shouldn't , for now i insert the key into a property in the child, but it's just for NH's sake...